# Conditionally render the Button in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css, html

Hi  I need some help on the below code, kindly help me out for this. As per need : user can click or use the undo button once the firing of the first event gets completed. Explain:

```javascript
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dataPassedevent', { detail: { type: 'cor'} }));
```

Once these event fired on the click of the 'correct' button and completed its job on the parent ,,, then only user can see and use the 'Undo' button.

code :

```javascript
     handlecorrectBut() {
        if (!this.Corrected) {
                this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dataPassedevent', { detail: { type: 'cor'} }));
                this.CAn = true;
                this.InCAn = false;
                this.An = true;
            }
        }
```

```html
     <button title="Correct Answer" onclick={handlecorrectBut}>
             <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:success" size="small" variant="bare"
                  alternative-text="Correct Answer">
             </lightning-icon>
      </button>
```

```javascript
    handleundoButton() {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('datapassedevent', { detail: { type: 'un'} }));
            this.CAn = false;
            this.InCAn = false;
            this.An = false;
        }
```

```html
    <button title="Undo onclick={handleundoButton}>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:undo" size="small" variant="bare" alternative-text="Undo">
             </lightning-icon>
    </button>
```

Note : Set timeout is not advisable here
kindly help me out for this

Answer (score 0):

> first thing, The custom event name must be in lowercase. You need to
> change **dataPassedevent** to **datapassedevent**.

Now,

You can simply use a public property to identify weather the job has been completed on parent when event fires from child.

In child, define a public property:-

```
@api jobFinishedInParent = false;
```

In Parent, define a private property:-

```
jobFinished = false;
```

and pass it to child like below:-

```
<template>
    <c-child ondatapassedevent={handleDataPassedEvent} job-finished-in-parent={jobFinished}><c-child>
</template>
```

In the js of the parent,

```
handleDataPassedEvent(event){
  //do the job
  //then
  this.jobFinished = true;
}
```

This way, you can identify in child weather the job has been completed in parent or not.

Use if:true directive to show hide the undo button conditionally. In child html, you need to use like this:-

```
<template if:true={jobFinishedInParent}>
     <button title="Undo onclick={handleundoButton}>
        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:undo" size="small" variant="bare" alternative-text="Undo">
         </lightning-icon>
    </button>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi @Saket jobfinishedinparent === undefined is coming in the child compoent kindly help

Comment: Hi saket jobFinishedInParent==false in chile compoent kindly help

Comment: @Tia please update your question with what you have tried

Comment: Yes i got the value as true but still user can click on the undo button befor job gets completed

Comment: please read my updated answer

Comment: Yes i have done like this only in my HTML

Comment: this thing dosen't work ,,,it will render the same situation....